# Meteor: names defined in lib/* not loading

Tags: web-applications, coffeescript, meteor

I'm not seeing the functions and constants in my lib/ directory show up on the client (or server, AFAIK).

I've defined some general helper functions in a file called generalDOM.coffee, which is located in my lib directory under the root of my application; however, when the client code runs, I get the error

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: BACKSLASH is not defined"
```

BACKSLASH is just the name of a constant. If I move the declaration to the Page.coffee file where it is used, it works as expected. For obvious reasons, though, I would prefer to locate the shared code in a shared place. Moreover, I would prefer to understand what's going on here.

The docs indicate that lib/* is loaded first, so I'm confused. Looking at other examples such as the structure of [this app](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/tree/03f0307d0b178a08880bb2125160631185dac92b/lib) makes me think my way ought to work.

I've got the following under the root:
README.md   lib     public      smart.lock
client      packages    server      tests
collections private     smart.json

Answer (score 1):

So, looks like the issue was how meteor handles var, and my not correcting for coffee->js when comparing code. Adding the @ designator to my declarations put them in the global namespace, so now it works.